# how can I acces a Github repo from a 2nd machine?

Tags: ssh, github

Although there is a number of questions on the topic, I'm not getting anywhere....

I need to access an existing repo on Github from an alternate machine and I'm having trouble setting it up.

So I have installed Github and ran:

```
git config global --user.name
git config global --user.email
git init
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

I'm getting `Permisson Denied (publickey)`

Which I guess is due to me not having provided my SSH key. I have the key here, but no clue, what to do.

**Question**:
How to do I supply the SSH key to be able to connect my 2nd PC to my git repo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register another ssh key with github for the second computer.

Go [here](https://github.com/settings/ssh) and add another key. [This page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) explains the process.

Comment: I'm still stuck on generating the key... although the folder exists, I'm getting `no such file or directory` when trying to save the SSH key. What's wrong with `(/c/Dokumente und Einstellungen/me/.ssh/id_rsa):`

Comment: ok. got it work, although I'm still being rejected commits, because `tip of current branch is behind`. I'll figure this one out though. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to `https` authentication if you don't want to generate another pair of key or transfer your existing one to the new box.

You will need to change your clone command to following: `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

Their help section has a nice step-by-step guide to setting up your machin: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-all.

Specifically, see step 4 for instructions on how to import a new key.